# Azure Graph API 2.0 error in refreshing token: Provided grant is invalid or malformed (AADSTS70000)

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, refresh-token

I'm following step by step guide on Microsoft's site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token), everything is working correctly but every time I try to refresh the access token, I get this error: AADSTS70000: Provided grant is invalid or malformed. error_codes: 70000.

I've created a Postman collection for testing, also downloaded the official postman collection from the Microsoft's site, everything is working correctly until the access token does not expire. When it expire, trying to refresh the token always lead to an error and I'm pretty stuck with it. I've double and triple checked correspondence between redirect_url, permission, grant, copy/paste errors, waited for the access_token to expire before trying to refresh... I've done almost 100 tests, and every time I'm stuck at the refresh part!

I start with doing the normal call to Microsoft Login API in my browser, and getting the code in query string from the browser (no problems here) (please note that client_id is URL encoded because, in my test environment, client id is an URL due to the configuration of the Drupal portan we're using, I'm truing to recreate the same behaviour in postman)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_guid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={myclient_id_urlencoded}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri_urlencoded}&scope=offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&state=12345
```

Then with the code in query string, i POST to the token endpoint:

```
POST /{tenant_guid}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com

Content-Type: application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a0456a8d-6979-491f-b61e-86b5d614c577

client_id={myclient_id_urlencoded}
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
redirect_uri={redirect_uri_urlencoded}
grant_type=authorization_code
client_secret={client_secret_urlencoded}
code=OAQABAAIAAADCoMpjJXrxTq9VG9te-7FXujKZhF...
```

I receive back an accesso token (that is working like a charm in accessing https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me for an hour) and a refresh token. I would love to get a new pair of access/refresh token when the original access token expires, using the refresh_token grant_type

```
POST /tenant_guid/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com

Content-Type: application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5d71f813-768e-476c-a97f-c109fba3165e

client_id={myclient_id_urlencoded}
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
redirect_uri={redirect_uri_urlencoded}
grant_type=refresh_token
cclient_secret={client_secret_urlencoded}
refresh_token=OAQABAAAAAADCoMpjJXrxTq9VG9te-7FX8m6YMg-.....
```

But no matter if I try before access token expiration or after, closing and reopening postman, I always receive that error back.  I've done almost 50 tests (always with the full round of login/authorization to use always a fresh refresh token) with no luck.

Seems like I'm missing something really stupid here because I can't imagine that everybody else is behaving correctly... but really can't find a way out!

Answer (score 1):

So I just got mine working!  Here are the required parameters I needed:

```
client_id = your client id
refresh_token = the refresh token here
grant_type = refresh_token,
client_secret = secret
```

NOTE:  Everything I read told me to URLEncode the values.  I found it worked with them UNENCODED - no idea if it will really make a difference or not.  Since it is going in the body of the post, which means it is TLS encrypted.

The other important thing was the url I posted to.  There seem to be so many examples and none seem to be consistent.  I used this format:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

The last thing is to be sure you are using the correct app id.  In my case I was using the appId for the wrong app and it didnt have consent.  Hope this helps.  I do wish Microsoft would make a concerted effort to spell out things consistently and think like someone who doesn't do security for a living.

Comment: Unfortunately, already tried to remove parameters leaving only the four you mentioned, tried with encoded and unencoded values... real no luck. 
Could you share maybe your code/postman? The postman call is exactly the same of the token request (that work seamlessy), but maybe for refresh token there's something different i cannot see...

Comment: So, I got my Postman scripts from an article on Microsoft website as a collection:  https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/f77994d794bab767596d
The page this link came from is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

The only thing I can think of is that the secret is EXTREMELY sensitive to being exact.  You mentioned having encoded it - try with out.

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved thanks yo the Azure Support.
The problem is the client id: as I supposed before, Microsoft allow you to define another application name, but always want to use the GUID client id to submit any request. Unfortunately, it was warning me when I didn't url-encoded it, but did not alert me that it was not correct until I tried to use the refresh token.

So just read very very well the documentation: client_id: The Application (client) ID **that the Azure portal – App registrations experience assigned to your app** (so not the one you choose).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Maybe including a format validation in the documentation would help!